# cant install python packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I have multiple versions of python install in my linux.

> ```
> python
> python2.7
> python2.7-config
> python2-config
> python2-jsonschema
> python2-pbr
> python3
> python3.4
> python3.4m
> python3.6
> python3.6-config
> python3.6m
> python3.6m-config
> python3-config
> python3m
> python3m-config
> python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script
> python-argcomplete-tcsh
> python-config
> python-faraday
> ```

I installed quandl package using pip. it's installed but when I run the code it says there is no module as quandl. I think its related to multiple versions of python.how can I uninstall these versions and which one i should uninstall and how can i install packages and run my code without any worry! I am a beginner so please help me.

Comment: What version of python your script is using?

Comment: script using python3 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Linux,if you are using Global environment You should use `python3.x` for all command-line operations as in **python3.4, python3.6 or pip3.4, pip3.6** when compiling so it installs to specified version.

for your problem to find the installed module run:

`pip3.4 list` `pip3.6 list` and `pip 2.7 list` and find quandl in them.

If it is not in the required version of yours, run: `pip[your-version] install quandl`

Comment: Still getting this  error ""ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Quand""

Comment: have you checked `pip3.x list` and found quandl in there it could also be a typo in the code. if the complete error is that [l is missing].

Comment: have you ran `python3.6 file.py`

Comment: Yes, I ran using python3.6  file.py. I am still getting the same Error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Quand"

Answer (score 0):

First, sure that pip3 is installed or install it.

ubuntu: `sudo apt install python3-pip --upgrade`

now, install your package with `pip3` instead of `pip`:

```
pip3 install quandl
```

I hope it will work:)

EDITED:

with this code, you create a virtualenv and run your script with it.

```
pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv -p python3.x venv //3.x will be version you want
source venv/bin/activate
pip install quandl, {and what else you want}
python script.py
```

for deactivating virtualenv, just run this in commandLine:

```
deavtivate
```

Comment: I installed pip3 and also quandl using pip 3 but it generates this error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Quandl'"

Comment: you are using virtualenv?

Comment: No, i don't think so!

Comment: You can use virtualenv to specify what version of python you want to use! if you want to use that, i post the answer to use virtualenv. i there any venv folder in your working directory?

Comment: I am just using python in a command line and its only one file in my directory and that's script.py

Comment: i explained how to create a virtualenv and use it in EDITED. hope it works

Comment: I used virtualenv as you described but still getting the same error.

Comment: run `python --version` after activating vitualenv. it should be the version you specified when you created virtualenv. if it was, run `pip list` and found quandl. if it was there, then I can't help you, sorry:((

Comment: Quandl was there in the list. I checked it

Comment: and python version? was specified version? make sure you run `python script.py`, not `python3.x script.py` after activating virtualenv.

Comment: Still getting the same Error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Quandl'
". I tried everything.